# Tkinter Python - listbox bind (multiple selection via key-value pairs in a dictionary)

Tags: python, tkinter, interface, bind

My dictionary contains keys that represent the various departments of the company. Each key contains N employees. My interface builds two listboxes in a window, where on one side all the departments are displayed, and on the other side all the employees. The implementation I want to achieve is: selecting multiple values at once. In other words, selecting a department and seeing its respective employees being selected in the adjacent list. Selecting multiple departments without losing previous selections. Clicking on a previously selected department should deselect its respective employees. Additionally, I need to be able to directly select individual employees without losing other selections.

My current code looks like this:

```
def update_workers(event):
        selected_departments = [department_listbox.get(idx) for idx in department_listbox.curselection()]
        current_selection = list(worker_listbox.curselection())
        worker_listbox.selection_clear(0, tk.END)
        for idx, worker in enumerate(all_workers):
            for department in selected_departments:
                if worker in workers_dict.get(department, []):
                    worker_listbox.selection_set(idx)
        for idx in current_selection:
            worker_listbox.selection_set(idx)
window = tk.Tk()
departments = list(workers_dict.keys())
department_listbox = tk.Listbox(window, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE)
department_listbox.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
for department in departments:
    department_listbox.insert(tk.END, department)
worker_listbox = tk.Listbox(window, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE)
worker_listbox.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
all_workers = []
for work_list in workers_dict.values():
    all_workers.extend(work_list)
for worker in all_workers:
    worker_listbox.insert(tk.END, worker)
department_listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", update_workers)
window.mainloop()
```

The lists appear, and I can select items from one side to the other. However I couldn't:

1. Ensure that the department is selected as it should be (on its respective side). Only its respective employees on the other side remain selected when it is clicked. I need both of them to be marked;
2. When I click it again, the selection is not undone as it should be (the employees remain selected). I need it to be undone when clicked twice, and so on;
3. When I click on a new department, its employees are properly selected, but the previous selection is lost. I need the selections to accumulate as the departments are clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I realized, while reading the documentation, that the implementation I intended wasn't possible with listboxes. With the help of GPT, I came up with the following code, using checkboxes instead listboxes:

```
def update_selection():
    selected_keys = [cb.cget("text") for cb in checkbuttons if cb.var.get()]
    product_listbox.selection_clear(0, tk.END)
    for idx, value in enumerate(product_listbox.get(0, tk.END)):
        for selected_key in selected_keys:
            if value in setores.get(selected_key, []):
                product_listbox.selection_set(idx)

def bind_checkbutton_events(checkbuttons, listbox_elements, selected_items):
    def update_selection_wrapper():
        update_selection()
        for item in selected_items:
            listbox_elements.selection_set(item)
    for checkbutton in checkbuttons:
        checkbutton.config(command=update_selection_wrapper)

window = tk.Tk()
# code for the window...
categories = list(setores.keys())

checkbuttons = []
for category in categories:
    var = tk.BooleanVar()
    checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(checkbox_frame, text=category, variable=var)
    checkbutton.var = var
    checkbutton.pack(anchor="w")
    checkbuttons.append(checkbutton)

product_listbox = tk.Listbox(window, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE)
product_listbox.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

all_products = []
for prod_list in setores.values():
    all_products.extend(prod_list)

for product in all_products:
    product_listbox.insert(tk.END, product)

selected_items = set()

checkboxes
bind_checkbutton_events(checkbuttons, product_listbox, selected_items)

Listbox
def handle_item_selection(event):
    selected_items.clear()
    for item in product_listbox.curselection():
        selected_items.add(item)
    update_selection()

    for item in selected_items:
        product_listbox.selection_set(item)

product_listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", handle_item_selection)

window.mainloop()
```

I am still facing some difficulties. When I need to select names individually, it changes the behavior of the checkboxes. And if, for some reason, I have selected a checkbox but need to UNCHECK one of the names, I need to click on it first and then uncheck the checkbox. This changes its behavior, causing it to NO LONGER affect all its values and only handle the last names clicked.